# Adjectifs dérivés de toponymes

Tags: adjectifs

Si l'adjectif pour Pékin est pékinois, quel est l'adjectif pour Beijing? I am making this text longer because you refuse to accept short questions.

Comment: What's the point about question's length ? We"re not robots, we see you're adding unnecessary text to your question.... The point of question length is that you should say what is your thoughts about the answer, the work you did trying to answer it yourself... not just "please do it for me"...

Comment: First, you're being a little rude, second *Pékin* is French for Beijing (and it looks like you know it) so your question doesn't make sense, third your "Drôle de langue, le français" is not very kindly, don't expect to have a warm welcome. Yes French has some quirks, especially City names that are sometimes translated, sometimes not, don't tell me English is any better.

Answer (score 1):

Beijing n'a pas lieu d'être en français, on doit dire Pékin et donc pékinois, voir [Le Monde](http://www.lemonde.fr/vous/article/2007/03/12/comment-nommer-les-habitants_881957_3238.html)

> Créée en 1987, la commission s'est d'abord penchée sur les noms des collectivités territoriales françaises, des pays étrangers et de leurs capitales. Ainsi, ont tranché les sages, on dit en français Pékin et non Beijing, Biélorussie et surtout pas Belarus et on parle du département de Maine-et-Loire, alors que l'usage hésite entre le féminin (la Maine-et-Loire, puisque la rivière qui donne son nom au département s'appelle la Maine) et le masculin (le Maine-et-Loire, en référence à l'ancienne province, le Maine).
>
> En savoir plus sur http://www.lemonde.fr/vous/article/2007/03/12/comment-nommer-les-habitants_881957_3238.html#889fpzx3lwBrB5lm.99

Comment: Evidemment on dit 'Les Anges' et non Los Angeles. A ne pas citer La Nouvelle Yorque. Drôle de langue, le français.

Comment: @B.Scholl: Pas vraiment, mais on dit quand même Nouvelle Orléans.

Comment: @B.Scholl Ça n'a rien de spécifique au français. Beaucoup de langues traduisent certains noms de villes et de pays. L'anglais dit *Munich*, *Cologne*, *Geneva* et *The Netherlands*, pas *München*, *Köln*, *Geneve* and *Nederlands*, l'italien dit *Monaco* (Munich), *Colonia*, *Pechino* (*Beijin*) et *Paesi Bassi*, l'espagnol dit *Londra* (London), *Ginebra* (Genève), *Pekín*, *Nueva-York*…

Comment: @B.Scholl cf: And then there's [this article, *Z’avez pas vu mon Beijinois?*,](https://legrandsoir.info/z-avez-pas-vu-mon-beijinois.html) that seems to imply that "Beijing" (and even "Beijinois") is being used by some in France, much to the author's justifiable chagrin.

Comment: @Papa Poule "Z'avez pas vu mon Beijinois?" is an ironic title. You can identify that by the "Z'" which shows that the one asking the question is a bad speaking french native.